# How to customized push notification in SchildiChat in local network

Tags: android, matrix, push-notification

I'm going to use **SchildiChat** Android version from [github.com](https://github.com/SchildiChat/SchildiChat-android) , and use in a local network so I can't connect to internet and get notification is very important . I can't use from Firebase to push notification .
I found some open source library bu I going to solve this problem in client.

- Can I change matrix push notification from client ?
- Do you know another way to solve this solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link [1]: https://github.com/SchildiChat/SchildiChat-android/blob/sc/docs/notifications.md#element-notification-implementations for handling notification in local server,
There are two ways for solve your soluion
1 - Foreground sync mode (Gplay and F-Droid)
2- F-Droid background Mode (using AlarmMaager)